# determining the current request in custom view helper zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to determine the current request in a view helper for zend framework 2. the purpose is to add the `class active` to the navigation element. Here is my current code:

```
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('companies'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Companies') ?></a>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('contacts'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Contacts') ?></a>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('tasks'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Tasks') ?></a>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('projects'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Projects') ?></a>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('reports'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Reports') ?></a>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('logout'); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Logout') ?></a>
```

As you can see, currently the home anchor is set to active.

My intentions are to do the following, per say:

```
            <li <?php echo $this->active('companies');?>
```

As you can see, I'm going to create a custom view helper called `active` that passes the companies module to the view helper. In the view helper, i need to access the request and ensure for this example the module is `companies`. So, any requests that use the company module would strategically set that navigation li element as active.

**So really my question is how do i access the current module in the request in a custom view helper.**

Comment: Why are you not using the [navigation view helpers](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html#view-helper-menu)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
        <?php
        namespace Sam\View\Helper;

        use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
        use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;

        class Active extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
        {
            protected $activemodule;

            use \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

            public function __invoke($module)
            {
                if($this->getRouteName() === $module){
                    return 'class="active"';
                }       
                return null;
            }

            public function getRouteName()
            {
                if (!$this->activemodule){          
                    $routeMatch = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
                    $this->activemodule = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
                }
                return $this->activemodule;
            }
        }
```